# Perl regex field separators

Tags: regex, perl

I have a small problem with one of my regular expressions. 
My data fields are set up as follows:

```
<3 spaces>my first column<3 spaces>my second column<3 spaces>etc.
```

My regular expression is

```
\s\s\s(.*?)\s\s\s
```

The issue I'm coming across is that the regex only matches every other column. That makes sense if regex is starting to be applied at the very end of the matching pattern not after the group definition - there is no set of three spaces for it to match at that point until the second column is reached.

How can I make this happen? My google-fu is failing me.

Comment: What does "matching every other column" mean?

Comment: The regex is matching the first column, then third, fifth, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use [look-around assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) in regexp

```
/(?<=\s\s\s)(.*?)(?=\s\s\s)/
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) can help:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = '   my first column   my second column   etc.';
my @cols = split /\s{3}/, $str;
print Dumper(\@cols);

__END__

$VAR1 = [
          '',
          'my first column',
          'my second column',
          'etc.'
        ];
```

Although, it does create a leading element.

Comment: You can strip leading and trailing spaces if you have to.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you use `split(/\s\s\s/, $line)`?

Comment: Although it is a Perl compatible regular expression I can't use split - it's input to be fed into another program. I wish it were that simple.

Comment: If you cannot use Perl, then you should not tag your question with Perl! Nor should you put "Perl" in the subject. You have asked for a Perl solution, and then rejected the solution because it was in Perl. Boggle!